For a covering $E\rightarrow B$, how does $\pi_b=\Pi_1(B)(b,b)$ act on $E$ (and related questions)?
In Tammo tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology, the author proves the following theorem (theorem 3.4.3 on page 74)

The following properties of $B$ are equivalent

$B$ is a transport space, i.e. $T$ is an equivalence of categories
$B$ has a universal covering right $G$-principal covering $p:E\rightarrow B$ with simply connected total space.


In the proof of $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, he says that since $\varepsilon_b:[\Pi_1(B),\text{SET}]\rightarrow \pi_b-\text{sets}$ and $T:\text{COV}_B\rightarrow [\Pi_1(B),\text{SET}]$ are equivalences, there exists a covering $p:E\rightarrow B$ whose $\pi_b$-set $F_b$ is isomorphic to the $\pi_b$-set $\pi_b$. And then he says that the morphisms $p\rightarrow p$ are in bijective correspondence with $\pi_b$-maps $F_b\rightarrow F_b$. I have no problem with this.
Now comes my first question. He then says that because $\pi_b$-maps $\pi_b\rightarrow\pi_b$ are right translations, $\pi_b$ acts simply and transitively on $E$. I've looked through the book, but I'm not sure when $\pi_b$ was defined to act on $E$. It has a left action on $F_b$ coming from the right action of $\pi_1(B,b)$ on $F_b$, for sure, but how does it act on $E$? And why must this action be free and transitive if the $\pi_b$-maps $\pi_b\rightarrow\pi_b$ are right translations?
My second question is: after he says that $\pi_b$ acts on $E$ simply and transitively, he concludes that $E$ is simply connected from the exact sequence of pointed sets $$1\rightarrow \pi_1(E,x)\rightarrow \pi_1(B,b)\rightarrow \pi_0(F_b,x)\rightarrow \pi_0(E,x)\rightarrow [x]$$
Why does he need $\pi_b$ to act on $E$ to conclude that $E$ is simply connected? The preimage of $[x]=\{x\}$ under $\pi_1(B,b)\rightarrow \pi_0(F_b,x)$ is the stabilizer of $[x]$ under the right action of $\pi_1(B,b)$ on $\pi_0(F_b)$ which is the stabilizer of $[x]$ of the left action of $\pi_b$ on $\pi_0(F_b)$. The action of $\pi_b$ on $\pi_0(F_b)=F_b$ is free (since $F_b$ is isomorphic to $\pi_b$ as $\pi_b$-sets), and so the preimage of $[x]$ under $\pi_1(B,b)\rightarrow \pi_0(F_b,x)$ is trivial, which means that $\pi_1(E,x)=1$. Is the action of $\pi_b$ on $F_b=\pi_0(F_b)$ not sufficient?
My third and final question now is: he then says that $\text{Aut}(p)$ acts properly discontinuously and transitively on $E$. I have no problem with the first part, but how is the second part proven? Does it follow from the fact that $\pi_b$ acts transitively on $E$, and if so, is that action by deck transformations?

Your observations are correct; this is just a typo. The $\pi_b$-set $F_b$ is isomorphic to the $\pi_b$-set $\pi_b$ (acting on itself via left translation) and this action is simply transitive by a direct inspection. For the corresponding covering $p\colon E\rightarrow B$, Proposition 3.2.8 tells us that transitivity is equivalent to $E$ being path-connected and the fundamental group of $E$ is isomorphic to a stabilizer subgroup of this action, hence trivial by simplicity. Thus, $E$ is simply connected.
For the last question, tom Dieck says "the induced action on each fibre is transitive". It is only now that the first paragraph of the Proof becomes relevant. The automorphisms of $p$ correspond to the $\pi_b$-maps $F_b\rightarrow F_b$ and this correspondence is given by restriction to the fiber, so $\mathrm{Aut}(p)$ acts transitively on $F_b$ if $\pi_b$ does and this is the case, as already observed. The same is true for any other fiber by a change of base point (since $B$ is path-connected).
Of course, I should add that post hoc $\pi_b$ does act on $E$ via the isomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(p)\cong\pi_b$ that we have just established.

Thank you! Two quick questions: on page 69 he says "From the construction of the transport functor it is immediate that the fibre transport $T_p([w]):F_b\rightarrow F_c$ is $G$-equivariant". He is considering a right $G$-principal covering in this specific case. More generally, is it true that the map $T_p([w]):F_b\rightarrow F_c$ is $\text{Aut}(p)$-equivariant for any covering $p:E\rightarrow B$? My second question is: how do we obtain the isomorphism $\pi_b\cong \text{Aut}(p)$?

For Question 1: Yes, this is also true "by construction", though I don't believe this is more general than the claim on page 69 as they apply to slightly different contexts. For Question 2: Yes, it depends on the isomorphism $F_b\cong\pi_b$. In the unpointed category, this is not canonical, but note the choice of this isomorphism is equivalent to the choice of a basepoint in $E$, so in the pointed category (where one often works), this action becomes canonical.

(sorry ignore this reply I'm posting it again because I seem to have deleted it) It seems to me that by the equivalence, we have an isomorphism $\text{Aut}(p)\rightarrow \text{Aut}(F_b)$ and then by a chosen $\pi_b$-isomorphism $F_b\rightarrow \pi_b$ yields an isomorphism $\text{Aut}{\pi_b-set}(F_b)\rightarrow \text{Aut}{\pi_b-set}(\pi_b)=\pi_b$. The action of $\pi_b$ on $E$ would depend on the isomorphism $F_b\rightarrow \pi_b$, right?

Thanks a lot for your replies. Merry Christmas!
